# Magento with paypal standard?

Tags: magento, paypal

Things goes like this:

I've read a lot about the Paypal Standard integrate with Magento... the problem here is that I can't get the paypal standard button to show up when check out or in the Payment method form.

I tried to disable everything and enable everything but the paypal payment didn't show up any thing. Even on the payment method page when check out...

I'm running 1.4.0.1, Please helpme resolve this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If PayPal is setup and working but you're not seeing the PayPal Express button on the one page checkout, make sure that "Payment Applicable From" is set to either "All Allowed Countries" or the country you and your customers are in.

You can find this under `System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Basic Settings - PayPal Express Payments`

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Under `System->Configuration->Payment Methods` the PayPal Website Payments Standard option is enabled
- Under `System->Configuration->PayPal Accounts` you've configured the Website Payments Standard section with your PayPal account info
- Under `System->Cache Management` try [refreshing the cache](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_cache/index#cache_control)

Comment: I tried to remove the cache as well as disable it, but the button are no where to be found. What's should be the problem, can you help me, I can provide the login to the admin if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your Base Currency to US Dollars? Or any of the other supported currencies?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency